# Is there a fast way to convert a package writtten in Python to Fortran 90?

Tags: python, fortran, fortran90

In a way, it is the opposite of this [fortan to python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222561/how-can-i-easily-convert-fortran-code-to-python-code-real-code-not-wrappers). For reference,  I was thinking of writing a Fortran 90 "port" of [qutip package](https://github.com/qutip/qutip). I know it will difficult to emulate everything in Fortran 90
due the lack of OOP (Object oriented programming) as in python. But well, I used to code in Fortran 90 before, so I still kind of like it. I know this is a silly reason. So, I am asking this question just to make a estimate how much work this conversion will entail. This will enable me to see when in my life, I could at least think of trying to do it.

Comment: Why not use F2003 which has better OO support? You could use it as an opportunity to learn the new stuff

Comment: yes. That seems to be a good idea.

Comment: If you need a reference for Fortran OOP, I'd highly recommend "Modern Fortran Explained: Incorporating Fortran 2018" by Metcalf et al. as a reference and textbook (CoI: I have no relationship with the authors or the publisher)